# Find numerical approximation for MLE of marginal distribution approximation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, monte-carlo, algorithms, joint-distribution

Say that I have the joint pdf $p(x,y)$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$ and that I'm looking for the maximiser $x_0$ of the marginal distribution $p(x)$. Suppose further that $p(x)$ cannot be computed analytically from $p(x,y)$. What sort of procedure could be used here?

Originally, I thought that I could perform a Monte Carlo approximation of the marginal distribution, and then use some searching algorithm to find the maximiser. Unfortunately, with the software that I'm stuck with, I don't believe that I can use the searching algorithm without having the analytical form of the objective function (the marginal distribution).

Comment: So p(x, y) is given as a formula or as a representative sample of p(x, y)? p(x) cannot bei computed from p(x,y) but what do you expect? Doe you expect a formula or a large sample? Might bootstrapping be a usefull procedure here?

Comment: p(x,y) is an explicit formula, but it cannot be integrated by hand to get p(x). I'm using this as a simplification. In reality, I have p(x1,x2,...,x11) and I need to maximize p(x1,x2,x3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the EM algorithm can be implemented, it is a natural approach for this type of marginal (or missing data) optimisation problem. In our book, [Introducing Monte Carlo methods with R](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa), there is an entire chapter on Monte Carlo optimisation, covering the optimisation of functions defined by integrals such as $$m(x) = \int p(x,y)\text{d}y$$by techniques such as

- EM
- optimisation of Monte Carlo approximations of $m(x)
- Monte Carlo EM
- stochastic gradient methods such as [Robbins-Monro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) replacing the gradient with a Monte Carlo approximation

With A. Doucet and S. Godsill, we further designed a [marginal optimisation algorithm called SAME](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013172322619) that exploits the marginal structure to design an automated simulated annealing algorithm. (This algorithm was [later re-invented](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/feedback-on-data-cloning/) under [other names](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/same-algorithm/).) Birge and Polson have a [similar version](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2135) involving slice sampling.